# Access external text file

Tags: java

Okay so i'm trying to make a simple program that can take a comma delimited list I've made in another file and pick a random name from said list and display it.

Is something like that possible in Java?

If so, where might I go to learn more about something like this, or can you guys give me an example on how this may work?

Comment: "Is something like that possible in Java?" - simple answer, yes, as pretty much anything can be done with java

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You need to learn some basic Java, look up how to read files.

Comment: Please try a Google search on "read external file Java".  46,400,000 results.  At least one of them should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you don't want do get a million downvotes, please read this - 
http://sscce.org/ and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask , and then come back.  If you want someone to take time out of their busy day to help you, you should show some level of effort in writing your question.

"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: OldProgrammer you should be ashamed of yourself. You can't just assume the worst in every person that is asking a question.

I can understand your frustration in maybe seeing a lot of bad questions but that's no excuse for just shoving my question away. If it's really that much of a bother for you to look at my question then feel free to ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutly no problem in Java. You may want to websearch (e.g. google) the following topics:

- "Java Read a whole File into String" (The goal is to have the complete file content inside a variable of type String)
- "Java split String with delimiter" (This will show you on how to get the values between the comma delimiter as an Array of Type String. At this time you know how many tokens there are inside your array)

=> Code of User Pazis but i recomend you try it on your own for learning purposes.

- "Java generate a random number from 1 to 4" (or something similar, it will show you how to generate a random number between 0 and your amount of tokens which will be important to not have  ArrayOutOfBounceExceptions).

Assumed you have at least basic java know-how you then just have to System.out.println(...) the element inside your tokens array that is located at the randomly generated index.

Comment: How do you guys think people learn something if you always just paste in final runnable code while i take the time to try to make them learn something? Is the kind of help i provide here even wanted on this plattform?

Comment: I'd say yes, your kind of help is welcome here.  It's informatative while still leaving room for learning.

Comment: This has also been pretty helpful. I've been searching on google but have been having trouble shifting through everything and knowing exactly what I needed to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's possible in Java!

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append('\n');
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
    String[] names = everything.split(",");
    System.out.print(names[randomGenerator.nextInt(100)]);
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Anyways, please make enough searches before asking such questions. Actually it was your first question here and I know you were not familiar with the community, so I didn't downvote your question, but others do as you see!

Comment: Thanks for helping out and not just blowing out of the water like some of the others.

I've actually looked online for some help but I've yet to really have any luck. I'm in a java class now but we've yet to touch on external file work. I guess I''ll have to just be patient for now. Thanks again for the help.